# how to prevent copy file out of hyper-v guest

Tags: hyper-v

we have some important files and apps installed in Hyper-V guest to be show to or operated by people,but we don't want they copy those content or apps out. Our host and Hyper-V guest are win 10.

Is there some way to disable clipboard between host and guest or other ways to prevent copying files out from guest?

Answer (score 1):

You should turn off Enhanced Session Mode in Windows 10.
Hyper-V Settings -> Enhanced Session Mode Policy on the left -> uncheck Allow Enhanced Session Mode